# Removing User Account From both Azure Active Directory and On-Prem Active Directory in a single Script run on ado pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have an Azure Active directory set up synced with on Prem Active Directory using Azure ADconnect with ADFS.

I am required to Automate the decommissioning process, few of my queries are as folows:

1. Does an simple "remove-msoluser" delete the user from On-prem too? if not, Does it sync back up in the next sync cycle ?
2. What is your preferred solution to achieve this in ADO pipelines? will I have to execute remote scripts on Windows Server AD?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would first delete the user from the on-prem AD. Then trigger the synchronization to remove the user from Azure AD.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/cannot-manage-objects

Comment: Hey Thanks, Do you recommend a way to achieve this in the pipelines ? I know about RSAT but not sure if that would work with Build agents. Is there a siggested way to remotely do this on the DCs ?